# How to pass a function into the Twilio's body and schedule

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, scheduled-tasks

```
def checkTemp():
    temp = res["main"]["temp"]
    condition = res['weather'][0]['main']
    while 5 < temp < 10:
        print("today = ", condition, ",temperature is", temp, "cold please wear more")
    else:
        while -10 < temp < 5:
            print("today = ", condition, ",temperature is", temp, "very cold")
            break
        else:
            while 15 < temp < 20:
                print("today = ", condition, ",temperature is", temp, "good weather")
                break


checkTemp()


def send_message():
    client = Client(keys.account_sid, keys.auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
        body=checkTemp,
        from_=keys.twilio_number,
        to=keys.target_number)

    print(message.body)

schedule.every().day.at("22:12").do(send_message(), checkTemp())

while True:

    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(2)
```

I want to pass the checkTemp() function into the Twilio body and schedule.

my phone receive the SMS from Twilio, but its display

```
sent from your Twilio trial account - <funciton checkTemp at 0x1b532340>
```

which is not what I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are passing the function object to the method that creates the SMS message. But you want to pass the result of calling the function. All you've missed for that are the brackets.

Your code says:

```py
body=checkTemp
```

but it should be:

```py
body=checkTemp()
```

Your `checkTemp` function will need to return a string so that it can be sent as a message:

```py
def checkTemp():
    temp = res["main"]["temp"]
    condition = res['weather'][0]['main']
    if 5 < temp and temp < 10:
        return "today = {condition}, temperature is {temp}, cold please wear more".format(condition = condition, temp =temp)
    elsif -10 < temp and temp < 5:
        return "today = {condition}, temperature is {temp}, very cold".format(condition = condition, temp =temp)
    elif 15 < temp and temp < 20:
        return "today = {condition}, temperature is {temp}, good weather".format(condition = condition, temp =temp)
    else:
        return "today = {condition}, temperature is {temp}".format(condition = condition, temp =temp)
```

Comment: after I added the bracket, I got error `line 205, in create raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: Message body is required.`

Comment: Oh, I wasn't reading that function! You need to return a string from the function, not just print.

Comment: I updated my answer with an idea of what `checkTemp` should look like. I also used `if/elif/else` instead of `while` because `while` expects to loop (which is why you needed `break` in there) and `if` is for conditional logic like this.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!